# How to convert this these commands in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, rpmbuild

am trying to build debian package using debuild command
since ubuntu does n't have spec file how to replace the content of
spec file to the ubuntu control file and also am facing issue while converting these below commands to ubuntu equivalent one
in below earlier while build the package we were passing spec file as an argument to the below command.(here $<)

```
rpmbuild  --buildroot=$(REPOS_DIR)/$(E1000E_BUILD_DIR) --define="_toproot $(REPOS_DIR)" --define "_rpmdir $(E1000E_BUILD_DIR)" -bb --noclean $<
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more detail. What do you want to convert to? What is the command supposed to do? Do you want to build a deb instead of an rpm? What do you currently have and what do you need?

Comment: You cannot "convert" those commands to Ubuntu. The process of building a DEB package is very different from building an RPM package. The [Ubuntu Packaging Guide](https://packaging.ubuntu.com/) is probably the best place to start.